# how can I loop through a range of date with dbt

Tags: dbt

What I want to accomplish is that, I need to load history data for a range of date, so I
have to run my dbt model multiple times with different date, for example, start_date = '2015-01-01' and end_date = '2015-01-05', the model will run 5 times with different value of dt.

what I've done so far is I wrote a macro below,however, something wrong with it and I can't change date variable as well.

```
{% macro run_model_by_date_range(model_name, start_date, end_date) %}
    {% set data_list = dbt_utils.date_spine(start_date, end_date) %}
    {% for date in date_list %}
        {% set target_model = model_name ~ '_' ~ date %}
        {{log("Running model: " ~ target_model, info = True)}}
        {% set sql %}
            {{ref(model_name)}}'
        {% endset %}
        {{run_query(sql, target_model)}}
    {% endfor%}
{% endmacro %}
```

the query below is the query of my model, I can just run & change for a single day once for this one.

```
{{
red shift unload config
}}
select * from spectrum.table_name_df where dt = {{var('date', dbt_date.yesterday())}}
```

thank you so much for any helping!!!!!